# Conectando Firebase con Android Studio bumblebee

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy tratando de conectar firebase con mi app, pero me encontre que en la nueva version de android Studio bumblebee cambio el build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Esto es lo que me aparece ahora en el build.gradle de proyecto, y en otro setting.gradle estaba el resto que aparecia comunmente

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

}
rootProject.name = "wewlu"
include ':app'
```

la cosa es que siguiendo las instrucciones de firebase, ya no aparece como ahí se indica. pues me dice que haga esto

```
buildscript {

  repositories {

    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):

    google()  // Google's Maven repository

  }

  dependencies {

    ...

    // Add this line

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

  }

}


allprojects {

  ...

  repositories {

    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):

    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    ...

  }

}
```

y a pesar que leyendo y averiguando logre agregar los repositorios no logro agregar el classpath de la dependencia
y solo consigo errores.

lo agregue asi

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

y nada de nada.

quedo atento a su ayuda gracias!

Comment: Hay dos archivos gradle: el del proyecto y el del módulo `app`, las dependencias van en éste último. De todos modos no queda claro cuál es el problema ¿? Si es un proyecto nuevo, intenta crearlo desde cero y luego modifica los gradle como explica la documentación. Si es un proyecto antiguo, recupera los gradle que funcionaban antes del problema y luego agrega lo respectivo a Firebase.

Comment: Es importante definir que errores, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que en android studio tenemos:

```
build.gradle(Project:nombre de tu proyecto)
build.gradle(Module:nombre de tu proyecto.app)
```

Las dependencias de Firebase se implementan en el segundo mencionado **build.gradle(Module:nombre de tu proyecto.app)** en el apartado:

```
dependencies{

}
```

También se puede realizar de una forma más sencilla desde la barra de herramientas de android studio con la implementación de Firebase, sin la necesidad de ir copiando y pegando las dependencias, todo lo hace de manera automática.
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugiero revisar [answer], saludos.